# AppStore App price

Tags: ios, app-store

I would like to know if there are any regulations from Apple how expansive an app is allowed to be - or are there any properties an app should have if it is very expansive - above 500$.

Comment: should probably be migrated to http://apple.stackexchange.com/ or http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The max price allowed by Apple is $999.99.  But I do believe that they examine top tier priced apps to ensure that they actually deliver meaningful functionality. See, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Rich